# Why do the ideals have to be irreducible for finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

I was reading some examples of finite fields from my class notes:

$\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ (Where $x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Z_2$)

$\Bbb R[x]/I$ where $I$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb R$

etc.

Here, I don't understand why the ideals have to be necessarily irreducible over the corresponding fields ($\Bbb R,\Bbb Z_2$).

As far as I know, any polynomial divided by a $2$ degree polynomial leaves behind a $1$ degree polynomial as remainder (which would form equivalence classes of remainders). A $3$ degree polynomial leaves behind a $2$ degree polynomial as remainder (which again form equivalence classes of remainders).

Could someone please explain why the ideal has to be irreducible?

Comment: That's because, usually one wants to obtain a field as the quotient.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate? @Bernard

Comment: The polynomial ring (in one indeterminate) over a field is a P.I.D., so maximal ideals are generated by irreducible polynomials (and vice-versa).

Comment: @Bernard What does P.I.D mean?

Comment: Principal ideal domain. The two main examples are $\mathbf Z$ and $K[X]$, $K$ a field.

Comment: Note the terminology: _maximal_ ideals of $K[x]$ are exactly the non-zero _prime_ ideals of $K[x]$ and they correspond to _irreducible_ (or _prime_) polynomials in $K[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $p(x)$ does not need to be irreducible in order for $\Bbb R[x]/\def\ang<#1>{\langle#1\rangle}\ang<p(x)>$ to be well defined. However, if $p(x)$ is reducible, then the ring $\Bbb R[x]/\ang<p(x)>$ will not have nice properties. For example, if $p(x)$ factors as $f(x)g(x)$, then the quotient ring will have zero divisors, as $f(x)g(x)=p(x)\equiv 0$. On the other hand, when $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $\Bbb R[x]/\ang<p(x)>$ is a field, which is very well behaved and well understood.

The same analysis applies when $\Bbb R$ is replaced with $\Bbb Z_2$ or any other field.

Comment: "The quotient ring will have zero divisors" Could you please give a concrete example of such $f(x)g(x)$ and $p(x)$? I just began studying abstract algebra a week ago and am finding it a bit difficult to understand without examples

Comment: Say we take $I$ as $x^2+2x+1$ in $\Bbb R[x]/I$ which can be factorized as $(x+1)^2$. What's the problem?

Comment: Then $(x+1)\cdot (x+1)=0$ in $\Bbb R[x]/I$. You know whenever two real numbers satisfy $xy=0$, then it must be true $x=0$ or $y=0$? Well, that familiar property is violated in your $\Bbb R[x]/I$, since $(x+1)\cdot (x+1)=0$, but $(x+1)\neq 0$. This is not necessarily a problem, but some applications will require the ring to have no zero divisors. This property is important enough that commutative rings which have it are given a special name: [integral domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).

Comment: I see. Interesting. But would $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ still be a finite field, or no? If no, why?

Comment: For a field I know the necessary conditions are 1) closure 2) associativity 3) commutativity and 4) existence of inverses. All of them seem to be satisfied for $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ (for both the operations + and .), isn't it?

Comment: Okay, but I'm finding your post contradict this. You called $\Bbb R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ a "ring" if it is reducible. But you called it a "field" when it is irreducible. Oops, I meant $\Bbb R[x]/\langle (x+1)^2\rangle$ in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry I I'm being annoying, but I seem to be very confused at this point. Maybe I should ask this as a separate question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77855/discussion-between-user48929-and-mike-earnest).